# How do I convert scientific notation to regular floating value. For example for the value 1.255555555569E10, I want 12555555555.69 as output

Tags: java

How do I convert scientific notation to regular floating value.
For example for the value 1.255555555569E10, I want 12555555555.69 as output.

I have tried the following way

```
Double val = new BigDecimal(1.25E10).doubleValue();
System.out.println(val);
// output : 1.23E10
```

I tried using long aswell

```
long val = new BigDecimal(1.25E10).longValueExact();
System.out.println(val);

// output is 12500000000
```

But long fails if the value has decimal like

```
long val = new BigDecimal(1.255555555569E10).longValueExact();
System.out.println(val);

// output is 12555555555

instead

// output should be  12555555555.69
```

please suggest.

Comment: "This is because the value is exceeding the range of Double" sure not! Otherwise `doubleValue()` would have returned Infinity (not to speak about [the double] `1.25E10`)

Answer (score 2):

You could take a look at `DecimalFormat`:

```
String pattern = "###,##0.00";
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat(pattern);
System.out.println(decimalFormat.format(1.25E10));
```

Sources:

- https://www.baeldung.com/java-decimalformat
- http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-internationalization/decimalformat.html

Comment: String val = new BigDecimal(1.23E7).toPlainString();
System.out.println(val); //output : 12555555555.6900005340576171875.This has also given me exact output.